# Removing elements that are subsets of other elements

Tags: list-manipulation, performance-tuning

For example, I have a list of lists:

```
l = {{a,b,c},{a,b,d},{d,e},{d},{a},{a,b},{f}};
```

And I want to remove all the lists that are contained in other lists:

```
lafter = {{a,b,c},{a,b,d},{d,e},{f}};
```

What is the most efficient way of doing this?  I know I could look at all the different sub lists, compare them to every other sublist and then select the ones that I want... but that seems inelegant.  Is there a "right way" to do this in Mathematica?

What is this called?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't think this question, at least as I understand it, has been sufficiently addressed.

I have come up with two different methods and since they each have strengths and weaknesses I shall present both, and then a hybrid method that attempts to be general.

These functions are still not optimal as needless comparisons are made (a set of the same length but different elements cannot contain the first, for example) or operations performed (ideally I would not need `DeleteDuplicates`).

### `Subsets`

For long lists of short subsets we can look at the problem in reverse.  By that I mean we can compute all the subsets (power set) for a given set and use that information to determine which elements to keep.  We can use `Sow` and the second parameter of `Reap` to collect (only) those subsets that appear in our master list.
Our function will sow each subset (from the master list) to each of its own subsets as tags.  We will `Scan` the list in a reverse `Sort` order to sow long sets first.

```
f1[lst_List] := With[{slst = Sort /@ lst}, DeleteDuplicates[
   Reap[# ~Sow~ Subsets@# & ~Scan~ Reverse@Sort@slst, slst][[2, All, 1, 1]]
  ]]
```

Test:

```
f1 @ {{2}, {4, 1}, {5, 2}, {1}, {5}, {3, 5, 1}, {0, 3, 5}, {2, 5, 4, 1}, {1, 4, 3}}
```

> ```
> {{1, 2, 4, 5}, {1, 3, 5}, {0, 3, 5}, {1, 3, 4}}
> ```

This formulation also handles duplicate elements in a single subset which the next function does not.  Subsets and subset elements are not returned in the the order they are given; I made the assumption that this is acceptable, but if not I'll address it later.

### Bit mask

As sets become longer generating a power set becomes impractical.  One can instead encode the contents of each set as a bit mask which allows faster comparison than a high-level `Intersection` etc.  (In later versions the `rls = . . .` code could likely be improved by using `ArrayComponents` but I chose not to program blind.)

At this point I make an assumption:  *there are no duplicate elements within a single subset.*

```
f2[l_List] := Module[{rls, out, test, unique = Union @@ l},
  test[a_, b_] := If[BitAnd[a, b]~MemberQ~a, ## &[], a];
  rls = Dispatch @ Thread[# -> 2^Range[0, Length@# - 1]] & @ Reverse @ unique;
  out = Table[test[#[[i]], #[[i + 1 ;;]]], {i, Length@#}] & @ Total[Sort@l /. rls, {2}];
  Pick[unique, #, 1] & /@ IntegerDigits[out, 2, Length @ unique]
]
```

Test:

```
f2 @ {{6, 12, 7, 4}, {10, 4, 1}, {12, 3}, {6, 9, 15}, {4, 9, 3, 7, 6, 2, 8, 5, 1, 11, 12, 15}}
```

> ```
> {{1, 4, 10}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 11, 12, 15}}
> ```

### Hybrid

We can now make a hybrid function that selects between these methods based on the input.  The test I'll use if very simple, checking only the length of the longest subset.  I have not attempted to optimize it.

```
hybrid[lst_List] := If[2^Max[Length /@ lst] < Length@lst, f1, f2][lst]
```

If you require the original subset and element order you can use the output from `hybrid` to extract these based on pattern matching.  The fastest method I found is rather convoluted, converting items to string to keep `Pick` from looking too deep.

```
ordered[lst_List] := 
  Pick[lst, ToString /@ Sort /@ lst, Alternatives @@ ToString /@ hybrid[lst]]
```

### Timings

So what does all this buy you over Mark's far simpler code?  Let's find out.

```
mark[lists_List] := With[{subsetQ = Intersection[##] == Sort[#] &},
   Select[lists, ! Or @@ Table[subsetQ[#, set], {set, Complement[lists, {#}]}] &]
 ]

SetAttributes[timeAvg, HoldFirst]
timeAvg[func_] := Do[If[# > 0.3, Return[#/5^i]] & @@ Timing@Do[func, {5^i}], {i, 0, 15}]
```

First with long subsets (calls `f2`):

```
lst = DeleteDuplicates[RandomSample[Range@200, #] & /@ RandomInteger[{1, 99}, 1000]];

timeAvg @ #[lst] & /@ {mark, hybrid, ordered}
```

> ```
> {13.26, 0.0998, 0.1342}
> ```

So 133X faster without ordering and 99X faster with.

Now the other data shape (calls `f1`):

```
lst = DeleteDuplicates[RandomSample[Range@20, #] & /@ RandomInteger[{1, 5}, 5000]];

timeAvg @ #[lst] & /@ {mark, hybrid, ordered}
```

> ```
> {32.651, 0.05244, 0.1122}
> ```

Here 622X faster without ordering and 291X with.

I'd say the extra code is worth it, no?

Comment: Thank you very much!  I'm always impressed by your answers.

Comment: @Andrew You're welcome, and I'm glad you liked it. :-) I put a good bit of work into this one.

Answer (score 9):

How about

```
subsetQ[set1_, set2_] := Intersection[set1, set2] == Sort[set1];
lists = {{a, b, c}, {a, b, d}, {d, e}, {d}, {a}, {a, b}, {f}};
Select[lists, ! Or @@ Table[subsetQ[#, set],
 {set, Complement[lists, {#}]}] &]
```

Let's pick this apart.  `Select[list, f]` selects from `list` all those elements `x` for which `f[x]` is `True`.  Now the `Table[..]` portion takes one of the elements (represented by `#`) of the `lists` and checks to see if it is a subet of each of the *other* lists.  Of course, we don't want to check `#` itself, hence the `Complement[..]` business.  Here's an illustration where `#={d}`:

```
Complement[lists, {{d}}]
dTest = Table[subsetQ[{d}, set], {set, Complement[lists, {{d}}]}]

(* Out1: {{a}, {f}, {a, b}, {d, e}, {a, b, c}, {a, b, d}} *)
(* Out2: {False, False, False, True, False, True} *)
```

Now, if anyone of these is `True`, we want to exclude that list.  Note that `Or@@dTest` returns `True` if any elment of the list `dTest` is `True`.

```
Or @@ dTest

(* Out: True *)
```

Slap the negator `!` in front, and we see that `{d}` is excluded.

If the lists are not ordered, however, then my `subsetQ` wasn't working; should take order into account.  This might fix it:

```
subsetQ[set1_, set2_] := Intersection[set1, set2] == Sort[set1];
lists = {{"test", "1"}, {"test", "1", "1"}, {"test", "1", "2"}, 
  {"test", "1", "3"}, {"test", "1", "4"}, {"test", "1", "5"}, 
  {"test", "2"}, {"test", "2", "1"}, {"test", "2", "2"}, 
  {"test", "2", "3"}};
Select[lists, ! Or @@ Table[subsetQ[#, set], {set, 
  Complement[lists, {#}]}] &] // InputForm

(* Out: {{"test", "1", "1"}, {"test", "1", "3"}, {"test", "1", "4"}, 
         {"test", "1", "5"}, {"test", "2", "2"}, {"test", "2", "3"}} *)
```

Is that what you're hoping for?

Comment: Probably not very high.  The `! Or @@ Table[subsetQ[#, set], {set, Complement[lists, {#}]}]` section isn't clear to me, care you expand on what that means?  Also, any idea why this doesn't work with strings?

Comment: I have tried it, and it works on symbols, but not on strings, which I don't really understand (I assume that the comparator for strings is different than for symbols, but I don't know how to fix it).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.  I'm trying to figure out why it isn't working for me.  My "test list" is: `{{"test", "1"}, {"test", "1", "1"}, {"test", "1", "2"}, {"test", "1", "3"}, {"test", "1", "4"}, {"test", "1", "5"}, {"test", "2"}, {"test", "2", "1"}, {"test", "2", "2"}, {"test", "2", "3"}};`  And the select line returns the entire list unmodified.  The first element is a subset of the next few elements, so it should be removed, along with the `{"test","2"}` element.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/5997/discussion-between-andrew-spott-and-mark-mcclure)

Comment: @AndrewSpott I've got to head out but I think I fixed it.  I'll be curious to hear!

Comment: That works for me, thank you very much.  The Select line is particularly helpful.

Comment: @AndrewSpott Awesome!  I just hope we get half as many hits as the xkcd extravaganza!

Comment: @MarkMcClure you got my vote. I tried, but failed miserably at getting this done. My solution almost worked, but the difference between almost working and actually does is enormous.

Comment: @rcollyer Thanks - that gets us one vote closer, but I see that xkcd got another 21 thousand votes since I left work.

Comment: @MarkMcClure yeah, only 21 thousand votes. It's been kinda slow ... :)

Answer (score 5):

You can use the Bentley-Clarkson-Levine algorithm that is encoded in `` Internal`ListMin `` to find the maximal elements of your list. To do so, we need to encode the elements as lists of 0s and 1s where the 0s indicate the symbols that are included in the list. For your example this would be

```
{{a,b,c      }, {a,b,  d    }, {d,e        }, {      d    }, {a          }, {a,b,       }, {          f}}
{{0,0,0,1,1,1}, {0,0,1,0,1,1}, {1,1,1,0,0,1}, {1,1,1,0,1,1}, {0,1,1,1,1,1}, {0,0,1,1,1,1}, {1,1,1,1,1,0}}
```

Now, consider `{a, b, c}` and `{a, b}`, or:

```
{a, b, c} -> {0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1}
{a, b}    -> {0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1}
```

For this pair, `` Internal`ListMin `` will remove `{0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1}` because it's "bigger" than `{0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1}` (the function is called `` Internal`ListMin ``, not `` Internal`ListMax `` after all). Using `` Internal`ListMin `` on the list gives:

```
Internal`ListMin[{{0,0,0,1,1,1}, {0,0,1,0,1,1}, {1,1,1,0,0,1}, {1,1,1,0,1,1}, {0,1,1,1,1,1}, {0,0,1,1,1,1}, {1,1,1,1,1,0}}]
```

> {{0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1}, {0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1}, {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
>     0}}

And this corresponds to the original sublists:

```
Pick[{a, b, c, d, e, f}, #, 0]& /@ %
```

> {{a, b, c}, {a, b, d}, {d, e}, {f}}

in agreement with the expected answer. Putting the above pieces together gives the following function:

```
PartialMaximum[l:{__List}]:=Module[{ass, un, indexed, s},
    un = Union @@ l;
    ass = AssociationThread[#, Range @ Length @ #]& @ Apply[Union] @ l;
    indexed = Replace[l, ass, {2}];
    s = ConstantArray[1, {Length[l], Length[ass]}];
    MapIndexed[(s[[First@#2, #1]] = 0)&, indexed];
    Pick[un, #, 0]& /@ Internal`ListMin @ s
]
```

Your example again:

```
PartialMaximum[{{a,b,c},{a,b,d},{d,e},{d},{a},{a,b},{f}}]
```

> {{a, b, c}, {a, b, d}, {d, e}, {f}}

A larger example:

```
lst = DeleteDuplicates[RandomSample[Range@200,#]&/@RandomInteger[{1,99},1000]];
PartialMaximum[lst]; //AbsoluteTiming
```

> {0.066836, Null}

In my experiments, this is slightly faster than MrWizard's answer.

Comment: Your solution is wonderful! Also, thank you for the name of the [algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxima_of_a_point_set#cite_ref-5).

Answer (score 1):

We can also construct a graph using  [`RelationGraph`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RelationGraph.html) with [`SubsetQ`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SubsetQ.html) as the first argument and get its source vertex list:

```
graph = SimpleGraph @ RelationGraph[SubsetQ, l]
GraphComputation`SourceVertexList @ graph
```

> {{a, b, c}, {a, b, d}, {d, e}, {f}}

```
SetProperty[graph, VertexShapeFunction -> "Name"]
```

[image]

Note: Don't expect this to be as fast as the other methods posted.