# k-subsets of several sets?

Tags: list-manipulation, performance-tuning, compile, subset

**Problem:** Let `A` and `B` be lists of lists of integers. I wish to find every `k`-element set, which is *a subset of one of the lists in `A`* but *not a subset of any of the lists in `B`*. In other words, given $A,B\subseteq2^V$, I wish to efficiently compute the set
$$\Big\{\sigma;\;|\sigma|\!=\!k,\: 
\sigma\in\big(\bigcup_{a\in A}2^a\big)\setminus\big(\bigcup_{b\in B}2^b\big)\Big\}.$$
We can assume the lists in `A` (and `B`) are pairwise incomparable (otherwise we replace `A` by its maximal elements via Carl Woll's [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/11386/removing-elements-that-are-subsets-of-other-elements)), and their elements are non-repeating (otherwise we use `DeleteDuplicates`).

**Test Examples:** In the code below, `A` (resp. `B`) consists of `nA` (resp. `nB`) randomly chosen subsets of an `n`-element set, with the number of elements in the range `rA` (resp. `rB`).

```
n=30; V=Range@n; nA=30; nB=300; rA={25,27}; rB={23,26}; 
A= Join@@Subsets[V,rA,{#}]& /@ RandomInteger[{1,Sum[Binomial[n,i],{i,rA[[1]],rA[[2]]}]},nA]; 
B= Join@@Subsets[V,rB,{#}]& /@ RandomInteger[{1,Sum[Binomial[n,i],{i,rB[[1]],rB[[2]]}]},nB];
```

Note that `B={}` is always an important case.

**Inefficient Solutions:**

```
subsets1[A_,B_,k_]:= Module[{X,Y}, X=ParallelCombine[DeleteDuplicates[Join@@Table[Subsets[s,{k}],{s,#}]]&,A,Union,Method->"CoarsestGrained"]; 
    If[B=!={},Y=ParallelCombine[DeleteDuplicates[Join@@Table[Subsets[s,{k}],{s,#}]]&,B,Union,Method->"CoarsestGrained"]; X=Complement[X,Y]; ]; X]; 
subsets2[A_,B_,k_]:= Module[{X={},aB,Y}, Do[Y=Subsets[a,{k}]; If[B=!={},aB=Intersection[a,#]& /@B; 
    Y=Complement[Y,ParallelCombine[DeleteDuplicates[Join@@Table[Subsets[s,{k}],{s,#}]]&,aB,Union,Method->"CoarsestGrained"]]]; X=X\[Union]Y,{a,A}]; X];
```

**Remark:** There are several difficulties. **(1)** If $a\!\in\!A$ have large intersections, then first computing all $2^a$ and than taking their union (deleting duplicates) is wasting RAM. **(2)** If $a\!\in\!A$ are small but $b\!\in\!B$ are large, then computing $X\!=\!\bigcup_{a\in A}\!2^a$ and $Y\!=\!\bigcup_{b\in B}\!2^b$ and then $X\!\setminus\!Y$ is wasting RAM because of $Y$. **(3)** If $A$ is large but its elements are small, then doing $X\!=\!\{\}$ and $X=X\cup\big(2^a\!\setminus\!\big(\!\bigcup_{b\in B}\!2^{a\cap b}\big)\Big)\big)$ for all $a\!\in\!A$ is slow because of changing $X$ many times with $\cup$.

**Motivation:** This is useful in math. For instance, `subsets[A,{},k]` are `k`-faces of a simplicial complex with facets `A`. Similarly, `subsets[A,B,k]` are generators of the relative chain complex of a simplicial pair with facets `A` and `B`.

Comment: If $\bigcup_{a\in A}\!a$ contains $n$ elements and we write sets as lists of 0's and 1's of length $n$, is there a quick way to check if $\sigma\in\bigcup_{b\in B}\!2^b$? Perhaps with matrix operations?

Comment: Is there a way to go through each element of $\bigcup_{a\in A}\!2^a$ only once? (iterator)

Comment: It would be useful to include code to generate example data for A and B

Comment: @SimonWoods I added the examples.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`BooleanCountingFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BooleanCountingFunction) along with [`SatisfiabilityInstances`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SatisfiabilityInstances). `BooleanCountingFunction[{k}, len][v]` indicates that exactly `k` of the variables `v` are [`True`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/True). `BooleanCountingFunction[k-1, len][v]` indicates that at most `k-1` of the variables `v` are [`True`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/True). A function that does this is:

```
KSubsets[A_, B_, k_] := Module[{a, b, s, v, set, bool, instances},
    (* exactly k elements from one of the a sets *)
    a = Or @@ (BooleanCountingFunction[{k}, Length[#]] @@ Thread[s[#]]& /@ A);
    
    (* less than k elements from each of the b sets *)
    b = And @@ (BooleanCountingFunction[k-1, Length[#]] @@ Thread[s[#]]& /@ B);
    
    (* variables *)
    v = BooleanVariables[a && b];
    
    (* exactly k elements *)
    set = BooleanCountingFunction[{k}, Length[v]] @@ v;
    
    (* boolean function *)
    bool = BooleanConvert[a && b && set, "BFF"];
    
    instances = SatisfiabilityInstances[bool, v, All];
    
    With[{i = v /. s[x_]:>x},
        Pick[i, #]& /@ instances
    ]
]
```

Your test data:

```
SeedRandom[1];
n=30;
V=Range@n;
nA=30;
nB=300;
rA={25,27};
rB={23,26};
A = Join@@Subsets[V,rA,{#}]&/@RandomInteger[{1,Sum[Binomial[n,i],{i,rA[[1]],rA[[2]]}]},nA];
B = Join@@Subsets[V,rB,{#}]&/@RandomInteger[{1,Sum[Binomial[n,i],{i,rB[[1]],rB[[2]]}]},nB];
```

Comparison with your function (on a reduced dataset):

```
r1 = subsets1[A[[;;10]], B[[;;135]], 8]; //AbsoluteTiming
r2 = KSubsets[A[[;;10]], B[[;;135]], 8]; //AbsoluteTiming

Sort[r1] === Sort[r2]
```

> {53.4153, Null}

> {0.496283, Null}

> True

Timing for the complete dataset:

```
KSubsets[A, B, 9] //Length //AbsoluteTiming
KSubsets[A, B, 10] //Length //AbsoluteTiming
KSubsets[A, B, 11] //Length //AbsoluteTiming
```

> {2.1075, 0}

> {6.16393, 8}

> {21.1174, 4016}

Comment: Thank you! But its performance seems worse then mine. I observed `AbsoluteTiming@MaxMemoryUsed@` when computing all simplices in the triangulation of the real projective space $\mathbb{P}^5$ (i.e. $|V|\!=\!63$, $|A|\!=\!2520$, $|a|\!=\!6$ for all $a\!\in\!A$, $|B|\!=\!0$, $0\!\leq\!k\!\leq\!6$). My `subsets1` needs `{0.140631, 3856800}`, but yours doesn't finish after 10min. Is there a way to fix this?